# youtube data API to rate the video

Tags: json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, codenameone

i followed the youtube data api to rate the video from the app. But i got "not found 404 error."

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=Z98hXV9GmzY&rating=like&access_token="+token+"&key=XXXXX
```

what is the right way to do that... Any help is appreciated. Thankyou

I'm using codename one platform for the app by the way..

```
Login gc = GoogleConnect.getInstance();
gc.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
                @Override
                public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
                    Dialog.show("Error Logging In", "There was an error logging in: " + errorMessage, "OK", null);
                }

                @Override
                public void loginSuccessful() {
                    Dialog.show("Logged In", "you are currently logged in ", "OK", null);

                }
            });
            if (!gc.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                gc.doLogin();
            } else {
                token = gc.getAccessToken().getToken();
            }
        });


        findLikes(f).addActionListener((e) -> {

            ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest() {

                @Override
                protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                    super.readResponse(input);
                }

                @Override
                protected void postResponse() {
                    super.postResponse();
                }

            };
            cr.setPost(false);
            cr.setUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=" + videoId + "&rating=like&access_token="+token+"&key=XXXXX");  //this doesnt give anything... is it not the right way??
            cr.setDuplicateSupported(true);
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not directly rate from the url. you need to use full rating code to give rate.
[Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate)

because firstly google authenticate of your application then it allows you to give rate Not directly from the 
[Your link](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=Z98hXV9GmzY&rating=like&access_token=%22%20token%20%22&key=XXXXX)

Comment: thanks 4 the reply... I have logged in using the google auth api, now I want to rate the video when a button is clicked. what do you mean by full rating code??

Comment: full rating code means full api code. you can find that code from https://github.com/youtube/api-samples

Comment: This is incorrect you if you check the documentation Like dislike and none are valid rating codes.   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate  His example sends like which is correct.

Comment: sorry Ajay i'm afraid i'm having hard time to get it done.. can you please elaborate a bit.. I have retrived the like and comment no and also sign in is done but like and comment insert is not happening... thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

First off please tell use what language you are using I cant figure it out exactly from your code.

[Videos: rate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate)  Add a like or dislike rating to a video or remove a rating from a video.

> **POST** https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate

Remember this call is a http post not a HTTP GET.   Ie you cant just place it in a web browser.

example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=b_bJQgZdjzo&rating=like&oauth_token={YOUR_accessTOken}
```

I am pretty sure it is oauth_token you use not key or access_token.

Comment: I read the documentations and all that, there are things about libraries and installed app etc.. I am using it in mobile app so can you kindly give me some hints. I think i'm not going in rt direction.. Thankyou